# A good metric to simultaneously compare both mean and variance

Tags: variance, mean, method-comparison

I am new to statistics, and have a fairly basic question. I have two sets of data that I want to compare with a third dataset. I am only interested in comparing the means and variances.

Turns out that the mean of dataset3 is close to that of dataset1. However, when it comes to variances, dataset2 and dataset3 show close agreement. So, I am not sure which dataset is actually similar to dataset3.

So, I would like to simultaneously compare means and variances. Is there a single metric using which I can compare both together? I am not aware of the distribution of both datasets.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

-ryan

Comment: Question - what is that  you want to achieve by comparing them simultaneously. One is measure of "center" of all data, and one is measure of how far the data is from "center". More context will be useful

Comment: Why not qualitatively report your findings? You can't really use statistics to convey how "close" datasets are,  anyway.

Comment: How about the CV--coefficient of variation, calculated as the std dev divided by the mean--a scale invariant measure of variability? It makes comparable objects that are widely different in mean and variance.

Comment: @AdamO: thanks, but there is a lot of such comparisons in my work. I can't be qualitative all the time.

Comment: @DJohnson: CV sounds like a very good idea! I will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Another statistic that provides a measure of the "distance" between two distributions in the K-S, Kolmogorov-Smirnov metric. That together with the CV should provide fairly good insights.

Comment: Or other distance/divergence measures like Mahalanobis distance or better, Bhattacharyya or Hellinger distance